# Cannot instantiate abstract class Net_SSH2

Tags: php, ssh

I am trying to ssh in a solaris server using php. I have downloaded a ssh2.php package from [this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pear/Net_SSH2/master/Net/SSH2.php)

and included it into my code. My code is following

```
<?php
include 'D:/MySoftwares/xampp/xampp/php/PEAR/Net_SSH2-master/Net/SSH2.php';

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('ip');
if (!$ssh->login('user', 'pass')) {
exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -ltrh');
?>
```

Now I am getting **"Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Net_SSH2 in D:\MySoftwares\xampp\xampp\htdocs\connectdas\contodas.php on line 4"**. 
I am a linux person and know little about php classes. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a instance of abstract class

see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php for more details

As i see in Net_SSH2 you can use **factory** method but you should create child class and define all abstract methods from Net_SSH2

or use existing class from lib

```
$ssh = Net_SSH2::factory('OpenSSH', $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your help sir! @Dolbik. I have found another way forward. It was plain and simple. I downloaded another Net package which has simpler class definition of Net_SSH2 and just included it in my code. For your convenience I am providing the package link here - [LINK](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpseclib/?source=typ_redirect)